# Problem on Winter '22 org - div with lwc:dom="manual", DOM access not honored when calling document.elementsFromPoint(x,y)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, winter22

Have an existing application with lwc:dom="manual" div.  Prior to Winter '22, issuing document.elementsFromPoint(x,y) returned expected "local" document elements (in our case - leaflet map markers).  Deploying the same application to Winter '22 org, the same call returns only an "HTML" element, which is not part of the "local" DOM.  It appears the lwc:dom="manual" is not being honored, at least for this function call, possibly for any document function.